# How do I store contents of a file in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have declared an edge as follows

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
```

My edges are read from a file and stored in edge_array[]

```
Edge edge_array[] = { Edge(A, C), Edge(B, B), Edge(B, D), Edge(B, E),
        Edge(C, B), Edge(C, D), Edge(D, E), Edge(E, A), Edge(E, B)
      };
```

Input file is like....

```
A C 1
B B 2
B D 3
```

For reading the graph I used

```
for(int i=1;i<=num_arcs;i++)
    {
        int f;
        int s,w;
        infile >> f>> s>>w;
        cout<<f<<s<<endl;
     }
```

Help me to store these edge details in edge_array as shown above.

Full source code is:

```
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main(){
    typedef adjacency_list <listS, vecS, directedS,
            no_property, property < edge_weight_t, int > > Graph;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    typedef boost::graph_traits <Graph>::edge_iterator edgeIt;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertexIt;
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;

    Graph G;
    std::ifstream infile("di1.dat");
    int num_arcs;

    if(infile >> num_arcs){
        std::cout << num_arcs << endl;
    }
    std::vector<Edge> edge_array;
    for(int i=0;i<=num_arcs;i++)
    {
        int f;
        int s,w;
        infile >> f>> s>>w;
        Edge E(f, s);
        edge_array.push_back(E);

    }
 for(int j=0;j<num_arcs;j++){
        cout<<edge_array[j]<<" ";

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try something yourself first - then ask if you have a *specific* problem. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: some problem is with the last for loop. can you help me sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a vector to store your data:

```
std::vector<Edge> edge_array;
```

Then read the file

```
for(int i=1; i<=edges; i++){
    infile >> f >> s >> w;
    Edge E(f, s);
    edge_array.push_back(E);
}
```

**EDIT**

First possible problem: you did not include vector

```
#include <vector>
```

Second possible problem: cout cannot print a pair

```
cout << edge_array[j].first << ", " << edge_array[j].second << endl;
```